# Can google index json generated content?

Tags: json, indexing, web-crawler

On a jekyll site of mine, I have a javascript file which contains about 50 products that are in JSON format.

I want to create a page with a url like this:

```
/browse?product=1
```

I will then write some javascript code to select the right bit of json and display the content on the page.

I know that google is able to index URLs like that above, but since in my case this content is going to be purely generated by javascript, is there anyway that google could index the pages?

And if not, is there a way I can make it do so?